# How do I use MatPlotLib and Pandas if there are full stops in my columns headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to extract data from multiple CSV files into Pandas dataframes and plot it using MatPlotLib. However, the column names have periods in them, like "Elapsedtime.secs"

How can I overcome the issues described below?

I tried plotting it anyway, as shown in the code below,

```
plt.plot(alt_100.AltitudeVar.ElapsedSecs,alt_100.AltitudeVar.Earth.Altitude )
```

but I got the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-70cb920d8826> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 plt.plot(alt_100.AltitudeVar.ElapsedSecs,alt_100.AltitudeVar.Earth.Altitude )

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5900         ):
   5901             return self[name]
-> 5902         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5903 
   5904     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'AltitudeVar'
```

I then tried putting quotation marks around the column name, as below,

```
plt.plot(alt_100.'AltitudeVar.ElapsedSecs',alt_100.'AltitudeVar.Earth.Altitude' )
```

this time giving me the error

```
  File "<ipython-input-24-2b982afb9579>", line 1
    plt.plot(alt_100.'AltitudeVar.ElapsedSecs',alt_100.'AltitudeVar.Earth.Altitude' )
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `plt.plot(alt_100['AltitudeVar.ElapsedSecs'],alt_100['AltitudeVar.Earth.Altitude'] )`

Comment: Alright, thank you! That works